# Kubernetes services with multiple ports

Tags: networking, service, kubernetes, ports

I have a problem with multi-port services. I try to expose two ports, the first one works, the other does not. I am testing this with telnet (amongst others), and I always get "connection refused" for the second port.

This is the part about the ports in the service's yaml:

```
spec:
 clusterIP: 10.97.153.249
 externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
 ports:
 - name: port-1
   nodePort: 32714
   port: 8080
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 8080
 - name: port-2
   nodePort: 32715
   port: 17176
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 17176
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first confirm that kubectl get svc shows the two NodePorts. If that is the case, then it is highly likely that the destination port in the pods are not working. Could you check in the pods if the ports are listening correctly? Then, I would also advise you to check the access using the ClusterIP as well.

Comment: get svc shows the two ports: "8080:32714/TCP,17175:32715/TCP". But netstats -tulpen only shows 8080 but not the other one. And what do you mean by checking the access using the ClusterIP?

Comment: Where did you execute the netstat command? If it is in the pod, then there is an issue in the pod, that has no applications listening in that port. If you executed the command in the host, then that 8080 is not the 8080 of the service, as it is all based on iptables rules.

Comment: By checking the ClusterIP, I mean accessing the service like 10.97.153.249:17176.

Comment: Thank you! After querying my application once, I can see the two ports, 8080 and 17176 within the pod. I still cannot access the second one (which should be accessible via 32715, the nodePort, right?). Trying to access the service via telnet and the clusterIP (from within the cluster) leads to "no route to host".

Comment: Wait a second, you say that get svc returns 8080:32714/TCP,17175:32715/TCP but it should be 8080:32714/TCP,17176:32715/TCP, right?

Comment: Thanks! yes, I confused some ports (not only the 17175 vs 17176 typo, but also internal vs. external ports). Now it works (or, at least I have other problems now, that do not seem to be related to the port anymore...). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to know! Do you consider the question answered?